# How to get content of a list object in a loop instead of list object itself?

Tags: python, numpy

```py
a = [[-5.0, 5.0, 0], 
     [-4.0, 5.0, 0],  
     [-3.0, 5.0, 0]]
```

This is my list. But I want to get list like this one down here.

```
b = [[-5.0, 5.0, 0],  
     [-4.0, 5.0, 0],  
     [-3.0, 5.0, 0],
     [-5.0, 5.0, 1],  
     [-4.0, 5.0, 1], 
     [-3.0, 5.0, 1],
     [-5.0, 5.0, 2], 
     [-4.0, 5.0, 2], 
     [-3.0, 5.0, 2]]
```

This is my code.

```
for x in np.arange(0,3,1):
    for y in range(len(a)):
        a[y][2]=x
        b.append(a[y])
```

But the output of this code is:

```
b = [[-5.0, 5.0, 2], 
     [-4.0, 5.0, 2], 
     [-3.0, 5.0, 2], 
     [-5.0, 5.0, 2], 
     [-4.0, 5.0, 2],
     [-3.0, 5.0, 2], 
     [-5.0, 5.0, 2],
     [-4.0, 5.0, 2], 
     [-3.0, 5.0, 2]]
```

So what's wrong with my code? How do I modify it to get the right result?

Comment: It is somewhat hard to tell what you are trying to do, but it looks like adding an index. I think you need to look more in-depth on how lists and numpy arrays work. In Python, they do not exactly use, or at least always need (kind of rare), the specific location identification ```[x][y]``` like in Java/C++

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix to your code if you insist on using lists, is:

```
for x in np.arange(0,3,1):
    for y in range(len(a)):
        a[y][2]=x
        b.append(a[y].copy())
```

output:

```
[[-5.0, 5.0, 0], [-4.0, 5.0, 0], [-3.0, 5.0, 0], [-5.0, 5.0, 1], [-4.0, 5.0, 1], [-3.0, 5.0, 1], [-5.0, 5.0, 2], [-4.0, 5.0, 2], [-3.0, 5.0, 2]]
```

**explanation**:

`a[y]` is a list. When you append it to `b`, you are appending the list object and not its content only. Then, in your next iteration you change `a[y][2]`. This will change the original `a` content (last index in it), which in turn will change `b` too. Therefore at the end, ALL `a`s in `b` will change, because they are ALL pointing to the same list object. To understand this better, see how this code changes the values.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
a[2] = 10
print(b)
```

b:

```
[1, 2, 10]
```

When you change `a`, `b` also changes because they are both pointing towards the same list object and changing one will change the other (they are actually the same object).

Now if you want to assign contents and not the object, you need to make a copy of it instead:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a.copy()
a[2] = 10
print(b)
```

b:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

However, if you are not required to use lists, I would suggest using numpy arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! If I use arrays, how does the last code in my loop need to be able to write the output I want ?